# Entire <div> hover and entire <div> clickable

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, hover

I'm trying to make the entire DIV clickable and the entire DIVs background change on the hover state. Why is my code not working?

```css
div.bottomLinks {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
div.bottomLinks a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
div.bottomLinks a:hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com">
  <div class="bottomLinks">
    Text for DIV link here
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS rules are backwards. Your div is a child of the anchor, not the other way around.

```css
div.bottomLinks {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
 a  div.bottomLinks{
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
 a:hover div.bottomLinks{
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com">
  <div class="bottomLinks">
    Text for DIV link here
  </div>
</a>
```

Or you could change the HTML instead and keep the CSS:

```css
div.bottomLinks {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
div.bottomLinks a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
div.bottomLinks a:hover {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomLinks">
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Text for DIV link here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, just make the div:hover, not the a. Try this

```
 div.bottomLinks:hover {
display: block;
background-color: #005596;
colour: #000;    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vh7tctbh/